# Dynamic menu bar with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, dom, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a menu bar using `Angularjs`. I've done similar things before with `Backbonejs`, but I have a hard time getting my head around how to do this with angular.

In my `html` file, I have the following menu placeholder.

```
<div id='menu1'></div>
<div id='menu2'></div>
<div id='menu3'></div>
<div id='menu4'></div>
<div id='menu5'></div>
```

A number of my angular modules add a menu when they are loaded (in `run`). Each of them only reserves a particular slot (i.e. `menu1..5`), so they don't clash. When some modules aren't loaded, their menu would not show in the menu bar.

An angular module would conceptually look like:

```
angular.module('myModule3', [])
  .service('someService', function($http) {
    // get some data to populate menu (use $http)
    this.menuItems = ['orange', 'apple', 'banana']
  })

  .run(['someService', function(someService) {
    // create a rendered menu item
    ...
    // insert it at id="menu3"
  })
```

For sake of simplicity, the rendered menu item should look like:

```
  <ul>
    <li>organge</li>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>banana</li>
  </ul>
```

I'm fairly new to angular, so I don't really know where to begin. I've been reading up on `directive`s, but don't see how they fit in here, as they require some custom markup (maybe a custom menu tag containing the DOM target (i.e. `menu..5`). Also, how to connect this to a controller is not clear to me.

**Update**
In addition to the above `base template` (containing arbitrary anchor points in the DOM) and the directive (which will produce a DOM element which will be inserted at these anchor points), a template will facilitate the creation of the DOM element. This template will be located in a separate file containing the position the directive's DOM element will be inserted to (as opposed to the usual case of directives in which an already existing tag will be replaced/inserted into specific markup that matches the directive's definition:

```
<menu ng-model="Model3DataService" target="#menu3">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="for item in items"></li>
  </ul>
</menu>
```

Again, coming from a Backbone/jquery background this makes sense, but this may not be the right thing to do in angular. If so, please let me know how I could keep the base template free of any knowledge about the modules and assumptions of where they put their menu (i.e. which slot of the menu bar they allocate). I'm happy to hear about other solutions...

Answer (score 5):

Each module should have its menu loader defined:

```
angular.module('module1', []).

factory('module1.menuLoader', function() {
    return function(callback) {
        callback(['oranges', 'bananas'])
    }
});
```

Your application should contain menu directive which can load menu items for any module only if exists.

```
angular.module('app', ['module1']).

directive('menu', ['$injector', function($injector) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: 
            '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li></ul>',
        scope: {},
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var menuLoaderName = $attrs.menu+'.menuLoader';
            if ($injector.has(menuLoaderName)) {
                var loaderFn = $injector.get(menuLoaderName);
                loaderFn(function(menuItems) {
                    $scope.items = menuItems;
                });
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Final html:

```
<div class="content">
    <div menu="module1"></div>
    <div menu="module2"></div>
    <div menu="module3"></div>
</div>
```

After running the application only module1 menu will be loaded. Other menu placeholders remain empty.

Live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/4tZQGSkJToGCirQ1cmb6

---

**Updated:** If you want to generate markup on the module side the best way is to put the template to the $templateCache in the module where it's defined and then pass the templateName to the application.

```
angular.module('module1', []).

factory('module1.menuLoader', ['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('module1Menu', '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li></ul>');
    return function(callback) {
        callback('module1Menu', ['oranges', 'bananas'])
    }
}]);


angular.module('app', ['module1'])

.directive('menu', ['$injector', function($injector) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: 
            '<div ng-include="menuTemplate"></div>',
        scope: {},
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var menuLoaderName = $attrs.menu+'.menuLoader';
            if ($injector.has(menuLoaderName)) {
                var loaderFn = $injector.get(menuLoaderName);
                loaderFn(function(menuTemplate, menuItems) {
                    $scope.menuTemplate = menuTemplate;
                    $scope.items = menuItems;
                });
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: In my case, I'd like to keep the base template in which the menu placeholders are defined module agnostic, i.e. the link to a particular placeholder should come from the definition of the menu (in the module). The markup for the menu (again, defined in each module), could be `<menu target="menu1></menu>` (which relates to the `div`s in my example).

Comment: You can generate markup on the module side. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's getting close to what I envisaged. The only problem left is the `<div menu="module1"></div>` on the base template side. It'll be much nicer if they just had ordinary `id`s and one could specify the target (the location at where the menu is getting inserted) on the client side.

Comment: If you want id then change `$attrs.menu` to `$attrs.id`. If you want `<menu>` instead `<div>` change `restrict: 'A'` to `restrict 'E'`.

Comment: We're not talking about the same thing here. In the module, I want to specify *where* to put the menu in the base template for instance by specifying an `id`. In your case, you already make this decision in the `base template`. Please have a look at my update.

Comment: Could you explain what is the purpose of hardcoding id of the target element inside of the menu html markup? It's a kind of an unusual use case when you configure your base template inside of other reusable components ... or maybe I'm still missing something.

Comment: The ids are generic and only denote a position in the menu bar. A module can choose to use it. I find it strange that I need to specify the position of the module's menu in the (generic) base template. It just "doesn't feel" right that every time, I decide to add another module, I have to also manipulate the base template. But perhaps that's how you do it in Angular. Also, you use a factory to provide the menu items. I might need to use a controller to keep items (which some of them are dynamic) and menu view in sync. I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that this doesn't work with factories.